# Using Hibernate inteceptors with Annotated setSessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application which uses Hibernate as the ORM tool. I would like to use interceptors to perform some tasks in the project. I have a NotesDAOImpl file, which has the DAO code.
Now when I want to use interceptors, I must create the sessionFactory with Configuration and StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.

Please mind my weird way of explaining this problem, I am not sure how to describe.

And this is giving me a problem as I am using the sessionFactory in the bean. I guess I will paste some code to make it clear :

NotesDAOImpl:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class NotesDAOImpl implements NotesDAO{

    @Autowired
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory=buildSessionFactory();

    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;


    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void shudtown(){
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().setInterceptor(new NotesInterceptor());
        configuration.configure();

        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }
```

Now If I try to integrate the buildSessionFactory method and the getSessionFactory() method in the NotesDAOImpl code, then the bean(Below) throws error(Error below) as it cannot find reference for sessionFactory. I cannot find any implementations of Interceptors which will work with my code. Any ideas?

Beans :

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"  />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Person2"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="asayhk2787" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"  />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Notes</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="connection.pool_size">200</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="c3p0.max_size">200</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                    ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Person beans being here -->
<beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="personService"
    class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Notes bean begin here -->
<beans:bean id="notesDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.NotesDAOImpl">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="notesService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.NotesServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="notesDAO" ref="notesDAO"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="LoginServiceImpl" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.LoginServiceImpl"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />

<!--  Beans for classes end here -->
```

Error code :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notesDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
```

Should I change the bean? I tried changing it to hibernate4TransactionManager, didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: u need to add @autoWired on the object of the sessionFactory that u have used into the repository.

Comment: Yes. I did that, but my problem is different, my bean definition prohibits me currently from using methods like buildSessionFactory and all. The bean cannot find sessionFactory then. I will edit the post to show what I mean more precisely.

Comment: @Krishna Check out the post now.

Comment: show me your sessionFacotry bean where it is?

Comment: @Krishna I have updated post to include my servlet-context.xml

Comment: if there is already sessionFactory that u configuring into the xml then why there is buildsessionfactory() method that u have defined? or just do one thing into the notesDAO bean just remove properties just for sec and run

Comment: Did that,  session = this.sessionFactory.openSession() throws null pointer exception. Also, I was trying to use buildSessionFactory as it is necessary for configuring intercpetor. I cannot find way to configure interceptor without using buildSessionFactory. There is one another way I found like this : final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(customInterceptor);, this also gives error. Source : http://learningviacode.blogspot.de/2012/07/testing-interceptor.html

Comment: have u tried with remove that properties from that notesDAO bean?

Comment: Yes, openSession throws null pointer exception as said above.

Comment: Why dont u register and configure serviceRegistry into the xml file it self because its not getting may be proper value so that is why sessionFacotry is getting null

Comment: Can you please show me an example, I am not so versed in this.How will that help me in using Interceptors?

Comment: I have not even done any example yet of this but may be its is good to get just bean by reference like we get in spring look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425049/how-to-wire-interdependent-beans-in-spring

Comment: That doesn't help me for creating the Interceptor though.

Comment: No need of buildsessionfactory() as you are injecting it using setter

Comment: and your property sessionFactory should not be static

Comment: @ShoaibChikate : Thanks, I will make it static. Can you please give me some Pseudo-code of how I can connect the class to Interceptor(4 hours already.). I have already extended EmptyInterceptor, I have everything ready, Just unable to connect NotesDAOImpl to it.